# FileNotFoundException when running Maven generated jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, resources, dependencies

Trying to create my first ever executable jar and am using Maven to do so.

The Java runs fine by itself but when I try and run the jar I get a FileNotFoundException for src\main\resources\sound.wav.

I think the problem is obviously in the pom.xml file and in the resources declaration, but my lack of experience with maven and jars and lack of idea means that I can't seem to fix it no matter how much fiddling I do.

My pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupID</groupId>
<artifactId>Main</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <finalName>MailCheck</finalName>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>sound.wav</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and my Java file looks like this:

```
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String password = "mypassword";
        String emailAddress = "myemail";

        String soundFile = "src\\main\\resources\\sound.wav";
        AudioStream as = null;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

        try
        {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundFile);
            as = new AudioStream(in);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", emailAddress, password);

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
            Message[] messages = inbox.search(ft);

            int unreadMail = 0;

            for (Message message : messages)
            {
                unreadMail++;

                if (unreadMail > 0)
                {
                    AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Open that jar and check audio file is there or not?

Comment: The file was there but I was trying to get an InputStream which is apparently impossible from a jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After package, this file should exist in the generated JAR. Please check this. And besides, you can not get `InputStream` of a file in a JAR like normal file in file system. You should try to get the `InputStream` from resource.

```
InputStream in = Main.class.getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/sound.wav");
```

Comment: Why all those \\'s? / is conventional.

Comment: That was the exact answer, thank you. The sound file was being included but I was trying to get an InputStream rather than doing what you said.

Comment: `src/main/resources/sound.wav` is an invalid path, `src/main` won't exist at runtime